# Vue trigger re-render of html even if computed properties didn't change

Tags: vue.js

I have a bootstrap modal with content including a tab-bar. I have computed properties that control active/hidden classes for tabs and panes.

```
<div class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ header }}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="" v-bind:class="[(tab1_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab1_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
                            <li class="" v-bind:class="[(tab2_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab2_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
                            <li class="" v-bind:class="[(tab3_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab3_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="pane1" v-bind:class="[(tab1_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab1_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="pane2" v-bind:class="[(tab2_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab2_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"></div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="pane3" v-bind:class="[(tab3_visible.val ? null : 'hidden'), (tab3_active.val ? 'active' : null )]"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I need the the modal to always be in it's initial state when it's opened. So i always want to rerender it on open even if the computed properties didn't change.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) to hook in to it's functionality. `show.bs.modal` will be emited from the modal itself before its shown, so you could at that point reset the content in the modal body.